# AssertionError for a list, but it is a list? What's going on?

Tags: python, list, assertion

We are doing something to practice writing tuples, sets, and lists, and I'm doing pretty well except for this here.

This is the code I made:

```
def all_but_last(seq):
    """
    Returns a new list containing all but the last element in the given list.
    If the list is empty, returns None.

    For example:
    - If we call all_but_last([1,2,3,4,5]), we'll get [1,2,3,4] in return
    - If we call all_but_last(["a","d",1,3,4,None]), we'll get ["a","d",1,3,4] in return
    - If we call all_but_last([]), we'll get None in return
    """
    
    if seq==[]:
        return None
    
    else:
    

        new_list=seq.pop()
        return new_list
```

And this is what I'm supposed to solve:

```
lst = []
assert_equal(None,all_but_last(lst))
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
nose.tools.assert_list_equal([1,2,3,4],all_but_last(lst))
lst = ["a","d",1,3,4,None]
nose.tools.assert_list_equal(["a","d",1,3,4],all_but_last(lst))
print("Success!")
```

Yet, this is what happens:

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-beb518954171> in <module>
      6 assert_equal(None,all_but_last(lst))
      7 lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
----> 8 nose.tools.assert_list_equal([1,2,3,4],all_but_last(lst))
      9 lst = ["a","d",1,3,4,None]
     10 nose.tools.assert_list_equal(["a","d",1,3,4],all_but_last(lst))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py in assertListEqual(self, list1, list2, msg)
   1056 
   1057         """
-> 1058         self.assertSequenceEqual(list1, list2, msg, seq_type=list)
   1059 
   1060     def assertTupleEqual(self, tuple1, tuple2, msg=None):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/unittest/case.py in assertSequenceEqual(self, seq1, seq2, msg, seq_type)
    962             if not isinstance(seq2, seq_type):
    963                 raise self.failureException('Second sequence is not a %s: %s'
--> 964                                         % (seq_type_name, safe_repr(seq2)))
    965         else:
    966             seq_type_name = "sequence"

AssertionError: Second sequence is not a list: 5
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The `.pop()` method returns the removed element rather than the remaining list. There must be a duplicate for this.

Comment: `list.pop` returns the popped item which would be the last element of your list by default. Assigning it back to `new_list` means the variable no longer contains a list considering the last item in your list is in itself not another list.

Answer (score 0):

`pop` returns the value that was removed, so when you do `new_list=seq.pop()` you are assigning `5` to `new_list`. And as the error says, 5 isn't a list.

What you want is just `seq.pop()` and `return seq`. That will remove the last value in the list and throw it away. Alternatively if you dont want to change in the input list, use `return seq[:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

`list.pop` does not create a list. It removes and returns item at index (default last):

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> ls.pop()
3
>>> ls
[1, 2]
```

A new list with all but the last item is usually written as a `[:-1]` slice:

```
>>> ls = [1,2,3]
>>> ls[:-1]
[1, 2]
>>> ls
[1, 2, 3]
```

The original list is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

`list.pop()` removes item from list and returns that item. You are returning single item from list